# Cluster simulator for Hadoop MapReduce

Tags: mapreduce, bigdata, virtual-machine, cluster-computing, simulator

I am looking for a cluster simulator to test my Hadoop MapReduce Java applications (Driver, Mappers, Reducers, ...).

There is something that could simulate the HDFS, the execution of the tasks of each virtual nodes?

I am not clearly interested in performances, I have a Intel Core i7 and 16GB RAM maybe that's enough to simulate a small cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to simulate your cluster.

1. Hortonworks or cloudera docker image , which you can spawn and connect to it in your code.
2. Run MR locally by setting 
   conf.set("fs.default.name", "file:///");
   conf.set("mapred.job.tracker", "local");

   See Integration test in : http://bytepadding.com/big-data/map-reduce/word-count-map-reduce/
3. Use  hbase-testing-util which spawns service of HDFS , HBASE as threads and cab be run loacally.

   http://bytepadding.com/big-data/hbase/hbase-readwrite-from-map-reduce/

Comment: I did not know Horton and it's enough, but I'll try the others too. Thanks!